# Type Definition of clone function

Tags: typescript

I have a clone function in js:

```
 var clone = (o) => {
        var obj = {};
        for (var key in o) {
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj[key] = o[key];
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

What is the proper type definition for it, in order that it guarantees that the cloned object is of the same type as the input object? Or do I even have to adjust the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a version that just works for JSON literals you can use the following:

```
var clone = <T>(o: T) => {
    var obj = <T>{};
    for (var key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = o[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

If you want a version that preserves the class that is more complicated, since you initialize the  result with `{}` the result will have a different type, so `instanceof MyClass` will not work for example. If you have an objects that have a default constructor you could use:

```
var clone = <T>(o: T) => {
    var obj : T = new (<any>o.constructor)();
    for (var key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = o[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Or if you want to mandate the existence of the default constructor and don't mind passing in the class you could also do:

```
var clone = <T>(o: T, ctor: new () => T) => {
    var obj:T  = new ctor();
    for (var key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = o[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
class AA {constructor(s: any) {}}
clone(new AA(1), AA); // Will cause an error
```

Comment: the second part seems incorrect to me. Using the `constructor` property to build an object you are not assured to build an object of the same class. This is because if you reassign `prototype`of your constructor to a plain object you still have `(new a.constructor() instanceof A) === true` but you have `a.constructor === Object`. A good way would be to use `Object.create` conjunction with `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Comment: @adz5A 10x for the feedback, You are right if you modify the prototype after you create the object, you the constructor may not be acurate, but your way also has disadvantages, namely the constructor will not get invoked, and that is where fields are initialized. I think it's more important to invoke the constructor, I believe modifying the `prototype`  after creation is a corner case. I will add a warning to the version using `constructor` to make it clear that if you switch the prototype the function may have incorrect outputs

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper type definition for it, in order that it guarantees that the cloned object is of the same type as the input object

Use [generics](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/generics.html).

```
var clone = <T>(o:T):T => {
```

Comment: generics don't work, since this function returns something of type `{}` and not of type `T`

Comment: @Ferenjito Yes they do, you can cast `{}` to `T` like I did in my answer.